# javascript function with 2 arguments is not working

Tags: javascript, php

**DEscription :**

I have a php script that displays the div on an html page

```
echo '<div class = "star_box" id = "'.$each_status['post_id'].'" onmousedown = "star_it(this.id)"></div>';
```

Now when I click on this div the star_it function gets called and it works perfect...

**The problem**

I want to pass another argument in the star it function .. like this

```
echo '<div class = "star_box" id = "'.$each_status['post_id'].'" onmousedown = "star_it(this.id,'.$each_status['regno'].')"></div>';
```

or a simple alphabet if any like `star_it(this.id,s)`

but when I do so the function stops working as when I click the div the function does not gets called ....

I dont know why I am stuck and now my star rating system does not work... I have absolutely no idea what is wrong

Anyone ??

Comment: Can you show us the code in your `star_it` function?

Comment: if the second attribute is a string or letter, add quotes around the parameter. otherwhise your php script will produce invalid syntax javascript.

Comment: What's the resulting markup of the second echo? Are you getting any JS errors? perhaps $each_status['regno'] is empty.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll thats not the point the star_it() if you really want to know should just alert me with two values passed for now .... it just doesn't do any this ... if I pass this.id it works good but as soon as the second argument comes I cant call the function

Comment: Does the `star_it` function accept a second argument? If it's not running at all, you're getting an error. Check your javascript console.

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** HTML. It should be pretty obvious what the problem is.

Comment: look at your debug console, e.g. shift-ctrl-J in firefox, look for JS errors. then look at the html you generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should modify your string quote's like this :**

```
<?php 
$status = "second test";
echo '<div class="star_box" id="'.$id.'" onmousedown="star_it(this.id,'."'".$status."'".');" >Hello</div>';
?>

<script>
    function star_it(foo1,foo2){
        console.log(foo1);
        console.log(foo2);
    }
</script>
```

This example works for me.

**So with your code :**

```
<?php 
echo '<div class="star_box" id="'.$id.'" onmousedown="star_it(this.id,'."'".$each_status['regno']."'".');" >Hello</div>';
?>
```

Comment: no. that's not "escaping". you're just quoting. for PHP->javascript insertion, you should ALWAYS use `echo json_encode($var)`

Comment: You sir are a life saver :) ... I am not really familiar with escaping strings quotes ... thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
echo '<div class = "star_box" id = "'.$each_status['post_id'].'" onmousedown = "star_it(this.id,\''.$each_status['regno'].'\')"></div>';
```

you forget to add \' before and after your string , the JS engine on the browser will treat your string as an undefined variable and the function will not work because of that .

//my English is not so good.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo '<div class = "star_box" id = "'.$each_status['post_id'].'" onmousedown = "star_it(this.id,\"'.$each_status['regno'].'\")"></div>';
```